Determining the absolute configurations of stereocenters in cyclic compounds
It is usually easy to determine which atoms are stereocenters, but determining their absolute configuration requires us to figure out the priorities of the groups attached to them. But how do we know where one group begins and ends in a cyclic compound?
Consider the following 1-ethyl-3-methylcyclohexane:

There are two stereogenic centers here - carbons 1 and 3, but how do I go about determining the priorities of their groups when I can't even figure out what the groups are exactly?

This might be helpful.

Moving away from the stereocenter, go clockwise around the ring and also counterclockwise around the ring. The first difference in the two paths determines the priority. For instance, if you start at carbon 1 (the stereocenter), you'll see that you get to a C atom that is bonded to 2 H atoms and 1 C atom (excluding the carbon you started at) if you go 1 carbon clockwise around the ring, and you'll get the same thing if you go 1 carbon counterclockwise. So no luck there. But then go an additional carbon clockwise and counterclockwise. On the clockwise path, you get to the carbon atom bonded to the methyl group, but on the counterclockwise path, you just get to a carbon bonded to 1 C atom and 2 H atoms. Since methyl>H in priority, the clockwise path wins, so it has higher priority. So notice that you never really need to figure out where each group "ends," you only care about how the two paths first differ. (If the two paths never differed, then it wouldn't be a stereocenter since you wouldn't have four different groups.) You should find that the configuration of that stereocenter is S.
